# Need to rewrite URL in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to rewrite the urls as below from your help.

i have this url for search

```
search-job.php?category=Accountancy&emp_type=Long+Term&working_pattern=Full+Time&location=Algeria&search=Search+Job
```

to

```
search-job-in-Accountancy-for-Full+Time-in-Algeria.html
```

OR from this

```
search-job.php?category=2&emp_type=2&working_pattern=2&location=12&search=Search+Job
```

To this

```
search-job-2-2-2-12.html
```

i have already done this

```
job-detail.php?j=Exalture-Software-Labs-Pvt-Ltd-Application-Developer-Websphere-Commerce-Suite-ais-GBS-in-India-Full-Time-Mumbai-11.html
```

To This

```
job-detail/Exalture-Software-Labs-Pvt-Ltd-Application-Developer-Websphere-Commerce-Suite-ais-GBS-in-India-Full-Time-Mumbai-11.html
```

My .htaccess is below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /temp

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+job-detail\.php\?j=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ job-detail/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^job-detail/([^/]+)/?$ job-detail.php?j=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Pls provide some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these additional rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search-job\.php\?category=([^&]*)&emp_type=([^&]*)&working_pattern=([^&]*)&location=([^&]*)&search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search-job-%1-%2-%3-%4? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^search-job-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*) search-job.php?category=$1&emp_type=$2&working_pattern=$3&location=$4&search=Search+Job [L,QSA]
```

Comment: can u pls provide some help how it will work.can u show me some result result that will created by this htaccess

Comment: After writing this long answer I really don't have time for further research. It works on same principles as the rule you already have. Let me if it doesn't work and do provide the URL for which it is not working.